# ADX azure dashboards passing parameters into query

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to pass in a string parameter from a single selection drop down in an adx azure dashboard to the following query:

```
.show ingestion failures
| where FailedOn > ago(7d)
| where Table == tableName
| summarize FailCount = count() by bin(FailedOn, 24h), Table, FailureKind
| evaluate pivot(Table, sum(FailCount))
```

The parameter being passed in is `tableName`

The error we get out is:

```
'where' operator: Failed to resolve column or scalar expression named 'tableName'
```

Printing the `tableName` value prints the expected string.

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I tried multiple approaches to resolve the error but nothing worked. And I think that `.show` command and parameter will not work together on ADX Dashboard. When I tried parameters with normal tables then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `.show ingestion failures` is a management or control command in KQL so it can't be preceded by query statements. When you run a parameter query in ADX dashboard it prepends the parameter in a `let tableName='sampleTable'` definition so that seems to be where the clash is.

One option is to move the ingestion failures into a separate table and then query that table directly. You can schedule a Data Factory run or similar automated system to run this on a frequent basis.

```
.set-or-append MyFailureTable <|
.show ingestion failures
```

Modify your ADX dashboard to query the data via:

```
MyFailureTable 
| where FailedOn > ago(7d)
| where Table == tableName
| summarize FailCount = count() by bin(FailedOn, 24h), Table, FailureKind
| evaluate pivot(Table, sum(FailCount))
```